# i am getting an error "cannot find symbol variable fragment"

Tags: android

I'm getting following error:

> cannot find symbol variable fragment

How to fix this error?

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.toi) {
        fragment= new FragmentOne();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();

        return true;
    }  else if ( id ==R.id.thehindu){

    }else if (id == R.id.support) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where does the error appear? It seems that it is not in the code that you posted

Comment: it says `cannot find symbol variable fragment` . @JuanCruzSoler

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
fragment= new FragmentOne();
```

To:

```
Fragment fragment= new FragmentOne();
```

Comment: Is there any other place where you use "fragment" variable? The error is happening because you are using "fragment" variable without declaring it first.

Comment: Show the import for your Fragment.

Comment: `package piestudio.opinion;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;`

Comment: do i need to paste something specifically ? like code of fragment or Main activity ? @GuilhermeP

Comment: After applying the fix i suggested, you are still getting same error? In the same place? Or did the error change?

Comment: @GuilhermeP 

`Error:(101, 32) error: incompatible types
required: Fragment
found:    FragmentOne`

Comment: @ron How did you defined the class FragmentOne?

Comment: @GuilhermeP thanks for being so helpful to me _/\_ . 
i replaced FragmentOne with Fragment and that error is gone but i m having this trouble .
`Error:Execution failed for task 'app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> JSR/RET are not supported with computeFrames option`

Comment: @ron In this line "ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);", you have to pass a variable "fragment". So, you have to create your own fragment (like you create an Activity)... It's impossible to help more with current code... Please, attach more code to your question

Comment: yes @GuilhermeP i have already created the Fragment with the name `FragmentOne` .i also created a layout for my Fragment and i named it i,e  ID = fragment1  .